# OpenEJB does not recognize eclipse classpath

Tags: eclipse, openejb

I have install OpenEJB eclipse plugin, but it seems openEJB server does not recognize project's class path. It works fine only if i copy all dependencies(third party jars) into OpenEJB/lib directory. Is there any other way to work around, specially eclipse configuration?? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin itself really isn't needed.  Possibly check out http://vimeo.com/6149008 which details using OpenEJB as a plain library in Eclipse for developing and testing EJBs.

With a little more details on the ultimate goal (development vs test vs production) I can probably give a better recommendation.

Comment: Thanks David for your answer, we wana use it for test env, so that we can run openEJB server in background and test changes in EJB without deploying it. I could write test class which initialize the openEJB enabling remotable and runing it for infinity thus it act as stand alone server. Asked above questions to know various other options available. btw OpenEJB is great work i realy liked it. thanx for OpenEJB :